# Ребята не могу разобраться в конфигурационном файле gulp для запуска проекта, выходит ошибка

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, node-modules

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\OpenServer\domains\opencart.loc\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (C:\OpenServer\domains\opencart.loc\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
at Object. (C:\OpenServer\domains\opencart.loc\gulpfile.js:32:6)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at requireOrImport (C:\Users\ignat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11) {
generatedMessage: false,
code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
actual: false,
expected: true,
operator: '=='
}
**Вот сам код**

```
// Подключаем Gulp и все необходимые библиотеки
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
        gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
        sass           = require('gulp-sass'),
        browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
        cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
        autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        bourbon        = require('node-bourbon'),
        ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp');

// Обновление страниц сайта на локальном сервере
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "opencart.loc",
        notify: false
    });
});

// Компиляция stylesheet.css
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('catalog/view/theme/apple/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('catalog/view/theme/apple/stylesheet/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

// Наблюдение за файлами
gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/apple/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/apple/template/**/*.tpl', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/apple/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/apple/libs/**/*', browserSync.reload);
});

// Выгрузка изменений на хостинг
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
    var conn = ftp.create({
        host:      'hostname.com',
        user:      'username',
        password:  'userpassword',
        parallel:  10,
        log: gutil.log
    });
    var globs = [
    'catalog/view/theme/apple/**'
    ];
    return gulp.src(globs, {buffer: false})
    .pipe(conn.dest('/path/to/folder/on/server'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

В gulp 4 поменялся синтаксис - если раньше можно указать функции для параллельного выполнения в [], то теперь необходимо использовать `gulp.parallel`

Например:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function() {}
```

Теперь превратится в:

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('sass', 'browser-sync'), function() {...})
```

https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098749/everytime-i-run-gulp-anything-i-get-a-assertion-error-task-function-must-be